# Table and view names containing UPPERCASES get returned as all lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql

The name of my database objects are standardized to pascal casing names, so:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId)
);
```

Suddenly (a few days now) any tables created by the following command produces a table without any cases in their name.

```
CREATE TABLE _Users LIKE Users;
CREATE TABLE `_Users` LIKE `Users`;
```

`lower_case_table_names` is default (for mac), so this is driving me crazy and makes no sense at all. What is going on here?

Comment: Delimit them, using back-ticks for MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh it doesn't matter. the produced table name will be lowered.

Comment: It's just karma for using Pascal casing... ;)  There was a bug long ago in MySQL that caused this behavior. I would have assumed that it would have been fixed by now, but maybe not. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20356

Comment: @TomH that is exactly the problem. the solution is to `CREATE TABLE __Users LIKE Users;` and then `RENAME TABLE __Users TO _Users;`. Post as a answer please? Thank you.

Comment: @TomH I think you should include the solution in your answer and edit my title to whatever makes this bug more accessible to people. I'm new here so I'm not so sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just karma for using Pascal casing... ;)

There was a bug long ago in MySQL that caused this behavior. I would have assumed that it would have been fixed by now, but maybe not.

The bug is explained here, with the latest update being in 2014: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20356

The solution, thanks to the OP, is to:

```
CREATE TABLE __Users LIKE Users;
```

and then:

```
RENAME TABLE __Users TO _Users;
```